# Optimize a function to iterate less into arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As a part of a CodeSignal challange i'm asked to :

> Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is
>   possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more
>   than one element from the array.
>
> For `sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]`, the output should be
>   `function(sequence) = false.` There is no one element in this array
>   that can be removed in order to get a strictly increasing sequence.
>
> For `sequence = [1, 3, 2]`, the output should be `function(sequence) =
>   true`. You can remove `3` from the array to get the strictly
>   increasing sequence `[1, 2]`.  Alternately, you can remove `2` to get
>   the strictly increasing sequence `[1, 3]`.
>
> Guaranteed constraints:
>   `2 ≤ sequence.length ≤ 105` &
>   `-105 ≤ sequence[i] ≤ 105.`

My code works but i'm looking for a more performant solution because the challenge has fixed the execution time limit of 4 seconds.

Here's my code:

```js
const almostIncreasingSequence = seq => {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < seq.length) {
    const filtred = [...seq];
    // splice 1 element at index i from array
    filtred.splice(i, 1);
    // create a `sorted` array with only unique numbers and sort it
    const sorted = [...new Set([...filtred].sort((a, b) => a - b))];
    if (filtred.join("") === sorted.join("")) {
      console.log(`filtred [${filtred}] ✅  sorted [${sorted}]`);
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log(`filtred [${filtred}]   sorted [${sorted}]`);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return false;
};

// array of random numbers for testing
const testArr = Array.from({ length: 100000 }, () =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
);
// [1,,N] for testing 
// const testArr = Array.apply(null, { length: 100001 }).map(Number.call, Number);

console.log(almostIncreasingSequence(testArr));
```

Comment: I think the problem is much, much simpler than your code suggests. All you need to do is go through the array checking to see if it's an increasing sequence. If you see an element that violates the pattern, set a flag and keep going. If you see *another* violation, return `false`. If you get to the end and there was just one, return `true`.

Comment: that's what I did at first but it kept exceeding execution limit time. Here's the function: 
```const isAsc = arr => {
  let j = 0;
  while (j < arr.length - 1) {
    if (arr[j] >= arr[j + 1]) {
      return false;
    }
    j++;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Well you don't want to *immediately* return false when you see an out-of-order value; you can allow one, so you need a separate variable to keep track of whether you've seen one earlier in the array.

Comment: No, i use the `ìsAsc` function to verify if the `filtred` array is ascending it returns `false` whenever `arr[i] >= arr[i+1]` so it's **loop in a loop**. The problem is not having a working code but a performant one which does not exceed the **execution time limit**.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a found index.

> This approach tests either three consecutive elements, like
>
> ```
>             v
> 1   2  [3   8   4]  5   6   7   -> found at index 3
> ```
>
> or takes for the next loop a check which omits the found value by checking the found index.
>
> ```
>                 v
> 1   2   3  [8   4   5]  6   7
>             ^ omit value on found index
> ```
>
> Then if not in sequence, the adjacent items are checked to prevent this pattern
>
> ```
>             v
> 1   2   3   1   2   5   6   7
>         3   >   2
>
>             v
> 1   2   3   8   2   5   6   7
>         3   >   2
> ```
>
> and if found, more than one element is in wrong position.

```js
function inSequence(array) {
    var i,
        found;
        
    for (i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if ((found === i - 1 || array[i - 1] < array[i]) && array[i] < array[i + 1]) continue;
        if (array[i - 1] >= array[i + 1] || found !== undefined) return false;
        found = i;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(inSequence([2, 1]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(inSequence([2, 1, 3]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 4, 3]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 9, 7]));
console.log(inSequence([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]));
console.log(inSequence([1, 2, 3, 8, 2, 5, 6, 7]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I think it's gonna fail on `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]` , should be false

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your array once for a worst case performance of O(n). Count the number of times the next number is less than the last (ie out of sequence) and also bomb out as soon as this has occurred more than once to improve performance where possible.

```
let sequenceTrue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let sequenceFalse = [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 2, 9];

function isAlmostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let index = 0; index < sequence.length && count <= 1; index++) {
    if (
      !!sequence[index - 1] 
      && sequence[index] <= sequence[index - 1]
    ) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count <= 1;
}

console.log("should be true", isAlmostIncreasingSequence(sequenceTrue));
console.log("should be false", isAlmostIncreasingSequence(sequenceFalse));
```

**EDIT:**
improve performance of the example above by removing the first check from the for loop and manually evaluate the first item in the array.

```
function isAlmostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  let count = 0;

  if (sequence[1] < sequence[0]) count++;
  for (let index = 1; index < sequence.length && count <= 1; index++) {
    if (sequence[index] <= sequence[index - 1]) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count <= 1;
}
```